# calculate Standard Error of parameter of Beta Function

Tags: r, standard-error

I'm learning **R** using a book called "Discovering Statistics using R". It's great but seems to skip over some areas.

So, I have a function in **R** that calculates the parameters `a, b` of the following pdf [beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaDistribution.html):

[image: func]

My function returns the following parameters found from a sample of 500:

```
  [1] 1.028316 2.095143 #a b
```

I'm trying to calculate the standard error of the parameters.

I'm wondering how this can be implemented in **R**?

As far as I can find online, [standard errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_error) are calculated from the sample, not the parameters. So, all i've implemented is, here:

```
    stderr <- function(x) sqrt(var(x)/length(x))
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your link shows how to calculate the standard error **of the mean**. However, since you seem to miss some statistical background, I believe you should first ask at stats.stackexchange.com how to do this in theory before you worry about an implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which function you're using to fit a beta distribution to your data, but the `fitdistr` function from the `MASS` package provides standard error values for the `shape1` and `shape2` parameters of the beta distribution:

```
# Obtain data to fit
set.seed(144)
data <- rbeta(500, 1, 2)

# Fit and output result
library(MASS)
fit <- fitdistr(data, "beta", start=list(shape1=0.5, shape2=0.5))
fit
#     shape1      shape2  
#   1.0596902   2.0406073 
#  (0.0602071) (0.1284133)
```

Here, the standard errors are 0.060 for `shape1` and 0.128 for `shape2`. You can get at the values with `fit$sd`.

Comment: I've written my own function but this is very useful. It returns slightly more accurate parameters than mine.